# Looping dataset in reverse order

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset with say 1 to 'n' number of DataTables in it and I want to loop it but in the reverse order ie, `from DataTable n to DataTable 1`. Can anyone suggest me a way to do this. I found some solutions but all are for sorting DataTables not Datasets.

```
DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
foreach (DataTable table in _ds.Tables)
{

}
```

Comment: why not simply use a for statement?

Comment: @CecilioPardo I don't understand why we search for complex solutions to what are otherwise very simple problems.  A for loop would be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ, you need to cast it because [`DataTableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataTable>` but only the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface:

```
var reversedTables = _ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Reverse();
foreach(DataTable table in reversedTables)
{
    // ...
}
```

or with a plain `for`-loop:

```
for (int i = _ds.Tables.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataTable table = _ds.Tables[i];
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use a `for-loop` instead:

```
DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
for (int i=_ds.Tables.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
{
   DataTable table = _ds.Tables[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or even simpler by decrement `i` within the *array indexer accessor*:

```
DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
for (int i=_ds.Tables.Count-1; i>=0; )
{
   DataTable table = _ds.Tables[i--];
}
```

or by using a *while-loop* doing the same:

```
int i=_ds.Tables.Count;
while (i>=0)
{
    DataTable table = _ds.Tables[i--];
};
```